# Can you write an interval function inside another interval function?

Tags: javascript, function, intervals

Is there any chance of writing this interval function inside another interval function? Right now it gets called every 0.25 seconds but I was thinking maybe if I put this interval on a counter? The inside of this function shown I only want that to be called every 1800 as shown below.

Right now its getting called every 0.25 seconds because it's been written inside another interval function. Problem is I need this function inside there, but I don't want it to run every 0.25 seconds instead 1800 as this function shows.

```
setInterval(function () {
      if (me.healthPoints > 0) {
        for (var i in Target.list) { //Player list
          var t = Target.list[i]
          var differenceX = me.x - t.x; //players x - targets x
          var differenceY = me.y - t.y; //players y - targets y
          me.angle = Math.atan2(differenceY, differenceX) / Math.PI * 180
          me.fireShot(me.angle); //target angle attack
        }
      }
    }
      , 1800);
```

Comment: you should post the outer interval function to get a better picture because the code you posted *should* be running every 1800 secs, not 0.25 secs. also why on earth would you need an interval of 1800 inside one of 0.25. º_º

Comment: The function is way too big, it collects all the player's data, the bullets and so much more every 0.25 seconds. But in the game I only want the enemy to be able to shoot back at me every 1800. Is there another way of making it shoot automatically? The only way around it to make it shoot automatically every x amount of seconds was with an interval function?

Comment: You can try to use setTimeout into set Interval.
Before you call the setTimeout, clear the current timeout.
https://jsfiddle.net/6snp3hjy/

Comment: then why don't you put the interval you posted outside the one with 0.25?

Comment: Every interval function is treated independently. It doesn't matter where it was started.

Comment: Why is it getting called after 0.25 second and not after 1800? I just tested and its running as expected. Put few logs and see if it actually gets called every 0.25 secs.

Comment: The problem is that every `0.25` secs you're starting another 1800 interval function, so you have multiple of them running.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do by starting one interval inside another.

Comment: Its getting called every 0.25 seconds because it's been put in another interval function, so it's going into the interval then calling it again and again which means that it's triggering like an unlimited amount of shots.

Comment: @Barmar Yes that's correct what you said.

Comment: So what do you really want to happen? If you want one thing running every 250 ms and another thing running every 1800 ms, why not just start them separately?

Comment: It's inside that 0.25 seconds interval so it gets called if not it won't get called, but I'm not sure what another way I could do this. I'm sorry I'm definitely a beginner coder.

Comment: Just call `setInterval` twice from the main code.

Comment: Okay, so would you not recommend the counter? Putting the interval around a counter? or would I get the same result?

Comment: You need to do this outside the other `setInterval`. You say you can't, but if you show us why, we can probably figure it out.

Comment: Just put it outside as @Barmar mentioned, I had it there in the past and with a bit of work with a clear interval it’s all working, thanks guys